# What is considered small, normal, large and xlarge screen sizes by android dashboards, in inches?

Tags: android

Reading [Android Dashboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens) I can see a separation of screen sizes in categories (Small, Normal, Large and Xlarge), but I can't find the actual size that these categories correspond to. 
I'd want something like:

- Normal = 4'' to 5''
- Large = 5'' to 6''

So my question is:

**What is considered small, normal, large and xlarge screen sizes by android dashboards, in inches?**

Answer (score 4):

The definition in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) is expressed in `dp`:

> - `xlarge` screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
> - `large` screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
> - `normal` screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
> - `small` screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

There are 160dp to the inch. So, you get:

- `xlarge` screens are at least 6" x 4.5"
- `large` screens are at least 4" x 3"
- `normal` screens are at least ~2.9" x 2"
- `small` screens are at least ~2.7" x 2"

Answer (score 0):

It is old information. Refer to this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

```
A set of four generalized sizes: small, normal, large, and xlarge

Note: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups are deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based on the available screen width.
```

But here are the sizes:

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```